# AngularJs custom directive isolated scope custom fields

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angularjs-scope

How can I add custom fields to angular scope along with passed fields as attributes, as the following:

```
angular.module('app')
    .directive("myDirective", function(){
        function NewObj()
        {
            this.id = 0;
            this.name = "";
        }
        return{
            restrict: "E",
            templateUrl:"partials/directives/temp.html",
            scope:{
                    viewId:"=",
                    dataObj: new NewObj() //This is the custom obj
                  }

             }
        }
```

---

When I do so, I get invalid isolated scope definition.
How can this be accomplised ?

Comment: Here's a decent explanation about directive scopes: http://umur.io/angularjs-directives-using-isolated-scope-with-attributes/

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The scope in a directive can only be one of '=', '&', '@'.
To do what you want, you can try something like:

```
angular.module('app')
.directive("myDirective", function() {
    function NewObj() {
        id = 0;
        this.name = "";
    }
    return {
        restrict: "E",
        templateUrl:"partials/directives/temp.html",
        scope: {
            viewId:"=",                    
        },
        controller: ['$scope', function($scope) {
            $scope.dataObj = new NewObj();
        }]
    };
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately, this won't let me reuse the same controller (with different parameters passed in the scope) for several directives.